# Formatting tables in PowerShell to export as CSV

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm seriously sleep deprived and stressed so it is probably extremely simple yet I still can't manage to figure it out.

I want to get an export of various things like services, processes, firewallrules, local users, whatever I need as a CSV but whenever I export it as such the csv only has 1 column in Excel when I open it.

I just want the output to be separated by columns so I can have a simple overview in Excel.

```
Get-Service | Sort-Object Status | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 10000 | Out-File -Append "C:\temp\Test.csv"
```

But this is the output I get:
[Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dJsOn.png)

This is what happens if I use a Export-CSV CMD: [Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opxeq.png)

Comment: `Format-Table` creates fixed-width table, not **C**omma **S**eparated **V**alues. You need to respect it in the text-import wizard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell's default CSV delimiter is a comma. To make Excel read the CSV properly, change it to a semicolon using the `-Delimiter` parameter:

```
Get-Service | sort Status | Export-Csv "C:\temp\Test.csv" -NoTypeInfo -Delim ";"
```

Or use the `-UseCulture` switch (thanks @JosefZ), which uses the same region-based ListSeperator-setting as Excel:

```
Get-Service | sort Status | Export-Csv "C:\temp\Test.csv" -NoTypeInfo -UseCulture
```

Comment: Yup, your second image is an Excel issue, not an export issue.

Comment: YESSSSS THAT WAS IT!!
Thanks so much Marsze, if you are ever in Amsterdam I'll buy you a coffee :D

Comment: Apply the `-UseCulture` switch instead of `-Delimiter ";"`

Answer (score 2):

Why not just export to csv then?

```
Get-Service | Select Name,DisplayName,Status | Sort-Object Status | Export-Csv "C:\temp\Test.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Same thing happens, I added a screenshot of that as well

Comment: @LeviHen Omit the `| Select Name,DisplayName,Status` part to get all properties.

Comment: @JosefZ I actually already did that as I want all the infos!! :D
No but seriously, all I want out of powershell is to give me a formatted table I can open in Excel and just drag and drop it onto Confluence or something like that for documenting customer environments.

I can use a TXT for myself (formatting there looks great) but there are some people who need to read through it in Excel, so I'm stuck with that for now :D

Comment: Not sure what @LeviHen is doing in Excel to cause those issues, but this answer works perfectly for me.

Comment: I was trying this on 2 systems, both of which feature a stock windows and stock office (2010 and 2016).

It has to do with the time/location probably, as when I started playing around with those settings I could get it to work, problem is I can't (shouldn't) change those settings on production servers ;)

Anyway, Marsze's solution above with the -delim ";" works for me and this purpose.

Comment: Interesting differences in regional settings. I wonder if the European delim default is a semicolon because of the comma in Euro pricing `€3,99`.. here in the UK it's a dot `£3.99` so the comma wouldn't split price columns.